# Semidirect Products and Representations

Tags: representation-theory

Assume that $G$ and $H$ are two $p$-groups and $k$ a field of $char(k)=p > 0$. Also, assume that i denote by $G \rtimes H$ the semidirect product of the above groups. Do you know if there is any coherency between the representation over $k$ of the group $G \rtimes H$ and the groups $G$ and $H$?

Comment: Classically this question is answered using Clifford theory. Maybe there is a modular version of Clifford theory; I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your response, to be honest i was expecting the above. And that's why i posted the question, because i couldn't find something in the books that i already know.